# How to find code from access violation address in a Delphi module?

Tags: delphi, dll, access-violation

Let me explain the problem by considering two dlls.
Lets say abc.exe is using xyz.dll. While running abc.exe(Delphi), getting an Access Violation.

> Project abc.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access Violation at address 39275E81 in module 'xyz.dll'. Write of address 737A24A4".

For some reason, I was unable to debug xyz.dll(which is also delphi).
So I would like to trace the code part in xyz.dll using addresses in above message. How can I find that code part ? Are there any other alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have source code for the mentioned DLL? If so then follow the instructions fromthe answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594293/3636228) question on how to properly debug DLL in Delphi

Comment: Yes, I have the source code. Thanks. I will follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party tools to trace exceptions in source code, or you can make your own. This simple one use JCL debug procs:

```
procedure AnyExceptionNotify(ExceptObj: TObject; ExceptAddr: Pointer; OSException: Boolean);
var
   ExceptLines: TStringList;
begin
   ExceptLines := TStringList.Create;
   try
      JclLastExceptStackListToStrings(ExceptLines, False, False, True);
      ExceptLines.Insert(0, 'ProcessID: ' + IntToStr(GetCurrentProcessID));
      ExceptLines.Insert(1, 'ThreadID: ' + TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID.ToString);
      ExceptLines.Insert(2, (ExceptObj as Exception).Message);
      ExceptLines.Insert(3, '[begin_stack_trace]');
      ExceptLines.Append('[end_stack_trace]');
      ExceptLines.SaveToFile('ExceptTrace.txt');
   finally
      ExceptLines.Free;
   end;
end;

initialization
   JclStartExceptionTracking;
   JclAddExceptNotifier(AnyExceptionNotify);
```

This way you will register any exception in your code and store the call stack of exception into file for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

that's All rigth ?

You can use two ways :

**1** Delphi Options >Debugger Option > Embarcadero Debugge> Language Exception, unckeck all options that are in "Exception types ton ignore ".

**2** Using debugger and view all objects, when you find the object with value `nil` you "found the problem".

**Remember**: The Acess violation Error is caused, by acess the object that never was created yet.